# How to send pageview for one subdomain from some other subdomain

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Suppose I have a blogging system where each category has its own subdomain like `python.blog.com, javascript.blog.com`.

`python.blog.com` lists all posts of python in an infinite list and I am sending pageviews for each article when it comes into view.

But once in a while, when the user is on `python.blog.com`, I pull in some articles from `javascript.blog.com` as related article and show it in the list between articles on `python.blog.com`. Now I want to send the pageview of article retrieved from `javascript.blog.com` from `python.blog.com`.

How would I do that in Google Analytics ?

Comment: Would you like to use the same GA property for all these hits, or there are several properties for different subdomains?

Comment: @kgrg I want to track using same GA id that I have registered for main domain **blog.com**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this makes sense for you it should work by setting the [location field](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#location).

```
ga('send','pageview', { 'location' : 'http://javascript.blog.com/path/to/article' });
```

Comment: Turns out with the pathname and page title, I also had to send the custom location/subdomain.